# How to get Identity User outside Razor Pages in Blazor Server-side?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, blazor, multi-tenant

I am working on a Blazor Server-Side application, using Microsoft Identity, Entity Framework and a multitenant approach with shared Db.

I have extended the IdentityUser class so that I could have the TenantId in the AspNetUser Table

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

}

Then I have applied a general query filter to my dbModel based on the TenantId

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasQueryFilter(a => a.TenantId == TenantId);
    }
```

In my blazor page I can call this function

```
public async Task SetTenant()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

    var user = authState.User;

    ApplicationUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Identity.Name);

    var TenatId = ApplicationUser.TenantId;

}
```

Finally in my service  I can get a list of Employees with the right TenantId

```
    public Task<Employee[]> GetEmployees(int TenatntID)
    {
    
        using (var ctx = new ProgramDbContext(TenantId))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(ctx.Employee.Select(d => new Employee
            {
                Id = d.Id,
                TenantId = d.TenantId,
                Name= d.Name,
            }).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

With this approach, everytime I want to call a function to get DB's Data, I need to identity the user and get the TenantId, then call the specific function and pass the tenantID to it.

I would like to know if my approach is completely wrong to implement this type of solution, for example:

1. Is it possible to add a Singleton service of an ApplicationUser, so that once is is identified after login, i can inject the service in every class where i need the ApplicationUser.TenantId?
2. Is it possible to identify and authenticate the Application User outside a blazor class? for example a plain C# class? I was able to pass the AuthenticationStateProvider and UserManager in the constructor of my Service class, but I cant await a function inside the constructor to actually get the ApplicationUser object.

   public CaronteWebService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider, UserManager userManager)
   {

   ```
        _AuthenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        _userManager = userManager;  

    }

    UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    AuthenticationStateProvider _AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a side note, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as this question needs more focus. To briefly answer your questions: 1. You can make something like `ApplicationUserProvider` and get the user based on `ClaimsPrincipal`. 2. You do not have to do it in the constructor. Add a method to the service `AuthUser(...)` and call it when you want to authenticate users.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.